# Problem with accessing a global variable in PHP

Tags: php, global-variables

Following is code snippet :

```
function something() {
$include_file = 'test.php';
if ( file_exists($include_file) ) {
    require_once ($include_file);
//      global $flag;
//        echo 'in main global scope flag='.$flag;
    test();
   }
}

something();

exit;

 //in test.php

$flag = 4;
function test() {
   global $flag;

   echo '<br/>in test flag="'.$flag.'"';
   if ($flag) {
       echo 'flag works';
     //do something
   }
}
```

The above code snippet, echoes 'global scope' $flag value properly but doesnt recognises the $flag with value 4, assumes null value for $flag .
Please point out what is wrong in accessing that $flag global variable.

Comment: If I add 'global $flag;' in function something, then it works, meaning not giving the undefined variable error. I dont understand this.

Comment: you have to declare the scope of the variable inside a function if you're trying to use a global variable. 

Its better practice not use global variables anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$flag = 4;` is not in the global scope.

> If the include occurs inside a
>   function within the calling file, then
>   all of the code contained in the
>   called file will behave as though it
>   had been defined inside that function.

-- PHP Manual page for [include](http://php.net/include), which also applies for include_once, require, and require_once

I'm going to make a guess that the error you're getting is on the `if ($flag)` line, because at that point, $flag is uninitialized, because the global $flag variable has never been assigned a value.

Incidentally, `echo 'global scope flag='.$flag;` isn't displaying the global flag either, as you need a `global $flag;` in that function to display the global copy, which also has the side effect of making `$flag = 4;` affect the global copy in the included file.

Answer (score 7):

You are running in a problem here simply because the way PHP is currently interpreting your file. You have nested functions.

Here is how your code currently executes:

```
function something() {
    $include_file = 'test.php';
    if ( file_exists($include_file) ) {
        //require_once ($include_file);

        $flag = 4;
        function test() {
           global $flag;

           echo '<br/>in test flag="'.$flag.'"';
           if ($flag) {
               echo 'flag works';
             //do something
           }
        }

        //end require_once ($include_file);

        test();
    }
}

something();

exit;
```

As you can see, when you assign the value of `4` to `$flag` (`$flag = 4`), you are within the scope of the function `something()`, not within the global scope.

In `test()`, since you declare `$flag` as global within that function, `$flag` is a totally different variable, global to the whole script.

In order to avoid this problem, use the superglobal [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/reserved.variables.globals). It's faster than using `global` anyway, and that way you don't get mingled in scoping issues as the ones above:

```
function something() {
    $include_file = 'test.php';
    if ( file_exists($include_file) ) {
        //require_once ($include_file);

        $GLOBALS['flag'] = 4;
        function test() {
           global $flag;

           echo '<br/>in test flag="'.$GLOBALS['flag'].'"';
           if ($GLOBALS['flag']) {
               echo 'flag works';
             //do something
           }
        }

        //end require_once ($include_file);

        test();
    }
}

something();

echo $flag; //echos 4

exit;
```

Comment: +1, just for completeness: `global $flag; require_once ($include_file);` would also do the trick. But this whole global/function/require thingy seems hackish to me, anyway.

Comment: Actually, while this is mostly correct, the test() function is moved outside of the something() function: "all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope." http://php.net/include

Comment: But the same happens if you write the function definition literally into the "outer" function. So the example is correct in this point, too.

Comment: @VolkerK:  Whoops, so they are.  I guess I've never used them that way.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Actually, PHP5.3 has closures now, so the documentation is outdated on this subject: http://php.net/closures . Even if so, `$flag = 4` is not moved into global scope.

Answer (score 2):

The line likely giving you problems is this one: `echo 'global scope flag'=$flag;`

Change it to: `echo 'global scope flag = '.$flag;`

**Edit:**
Now that you have edited you code snippet to by wrapping your code in the `something()` function, the problem becomes more clear. I think what is happening here is that the  when you initialize $flag with `$flag = 4;`, it's scope is within the `something()` method.

Try placing `$flag = 4;` above/before the line `function something() {`. Then all will be right with the world.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response.
that was a typo, corrected it.
But the original problem is still there.

Comment: OK, well with that line corrected, I see no other problems with the code you have posted. Your problem is within the `test()` method right? What happens if you access test.php directly? Same error?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `echo 'global scope flag'=$flag;` be `echo 'global scope flag =' . $flag;`

I received a different error. Which helped me fix the issue quickly.

> Parse error: parse error, unexpected
>   '=', expecting ',' or ';' in
>   D:\Websites (Apache)\Test
>   Site1\test.php on line 6

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this:

```
$myFlag = getFlag(); 
echo $myFlag; // output: whatever


// test.php 

$flag = 'whatever'; 

function getFlag(){
    global $flag;   
    return $flag; 
}
```

I would never set a variable in one script and call it from another file. this will cause extreme confusion down the road. Even my solution isn't the best. I would do this as a full blown class w/ ideally.

Comment: no, am echoing $flag after require, which means by then $flag has been defined. isnt it ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your original question has already been answered let me suggest another approach that avoids global variables all together.
You seemingly have a function + a default value that you set as a global variable. You can also define [default values for function parameters](http://docs.php.net/functions.arguments#functions.arguments.default).

```
<?php // test.php
function test($flags=4) {
  echo '<br/>in test flag="'.$flags.'"';
  if ($flags!=0) {
    echo ' flag works';
  }
}
```

No global variable, but you can still call test() without a parameter and the function will use the default value - which you can overwrite by passing the parameter.

```
function something() {
  $include_file = 'test.php';
  if ( file_exists($include_file) ) {
    require_once ($include_file);
    echo "\nwithout parameter: "; test();
    echo "\nwith a parameter: "; test(16);
  }
}
something();
exit;
```

prints

```
without parameter: <br/>in test flag="4" flag works
with a parameter: <br/>in test flag="16" flag works
```

That's not *exactly* the same behavior but it *may be* what you wanted in the first place....

edit: Another point could be the

```
if ( file_exists($include_file) ) {
  require_once ($include_file);
```

construct you're using. I don't have a strong opinion (or any strong evidence ;-)) on that but you might want to consider using

```
$something = include $include_file;
if ( false!==$something ) { /* error handling here... */ }
```

instead. [include](http://docs.php.net/include) "returns" false if php can't include the file. All that's required for this to work is that the included file doesn't explicitly return FALSE. This *might* be cache friendlier (e.g. when using something like [APC](http://docs.php.net/apc)). But again: I have no proof for this at hand, just a hunch. At least it gives your code a chance to handle an error "gracefully".